# Filtering values based on comparisons with adjacent columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, filtering

I want to compare column A in sheet 1 with column A in sheet 2, and only return matches from sheet 2.

I then, want to use the matching column A rows as a basis for a second comparison. The second comparison is to compare column B in sheet 1 with column B in sheet 2 and only return non matches from sheet 2.

Assume this is the data on sheet 1:

```
A   B
2   4
2   4
2   3
3   3
```

and this is the data on sheet 2:

```
A   B
2   4
3   3
2   4
3   3
```

So, only the third row will pass on both conditions. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: VBA solution okay?  If not, look up `MATCH` and `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Also, how do you want the result **returned** ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. *I want to compare column A in sheet 1 with column A in sheet 2 and only return matches from sheet 2*

Type on cell C1, on sheet 1:

```vb
=IF(A1=Sheet2!A1,"True","")
```

Drag the formula to all rows on column A, which contain non blank cells.

---

> 2. *The second comparison is to compare column B in sheet 1 with column B in sheet 2 and only return non matches from sheet 2.*

Type on cell D1, on Sheet 1:

```vb
=IF(AND(C1="True",B1<>Sheet2!B1),"True","")
```

Drag the formula down.

---

Output on Sheet 1 should be like that:

```vb
A   B   C       D
2   4   True    
2   4       
2   3   True    True
3   3   True
```

Filter column C by `True` to observe the "first" condition's returns. Do the same to column D to retrieve the data which satisfies the "second" condition.